# What measurement unit should I use for responsive design?

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

I am new in responsive design and am trying to figure out how to layout plugins of a site in smartphones. here is an example:

```
@media (min-width: 568px) {
.musicPlayer{
    width:600px;
    height:320px;
}
.Box, .List{
    float:left;        
}
.Box, .List{
    width:50%;
    height:100%;
}
}
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 568px) {
    .musicPlayer{
        width:600px;
        height:1200px;
    }
    .Box, .List{
        float:none;        
    }
    .Box, .List{
        width:100%;
        height:50%;
    }
}
```

As you can see I set the width or the `.musicPlayer` to `600px`. When I checked it on iPhone it was almost half of the page. But the entire width of iPhone is 320px, so how come 600px is half of that?! Thats why I thought maybe in responsive design they use a different unit such as em. Any idea?
Here is an example: http://goo.gl/Hje6XA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question, responsive design doesn't have an inherint unit of measurement that would cause this. You can use whatever you like in your CSS, pixels, ems, %,  ...

From what you describe, the first thing I would check is that you have included a viewport tag in the head of your page. Something like the following would get you started.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

If you omit this, smart phones will typically scale the page to make it fit, which isn't what you want for responsive design.

Also, although I don't think it's related to your problem, using min-device-width or max-device-width can sometimes complicate your life, especially if you are new to RWD.

You may find it easier to stay with min-width or max-width. Here's a little more info on the difference and how it relates to retina display. http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/cssmediaqueries2.shtml

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

You need to add to `<head>` tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

You should be using fluid grids with `%` for width, relative font sizes like `em` or `rem`. But if you are new in responsive design, maybe better check some frameworks like Foundation or Bootstrap and try to play with it.

Here is good place to start with design : http://learn.shayhowe.com/advanced-html-css/responsive-web-design/